# Regular Expression - Range (00-16)?

Tags: regex

I can't seem to get this regex quite right. I need to match a range number range from 00yo to 16yo but exclude any matches past 16.

The regex I am using at the moment is: `\b[0-1]?[0-9][\s\S]?yo\b` but it does not exclude matches past 16 and will match `50yo`.

Please note that I am searching data on a raw hard drive with the data only accessible in a stream. I cannot use `^` or `$` at start (the only option is to bookend the regex with a 'not' statement). I am using `\b` to limit the number of false positive matches. There is more than 1tb of data so I am trying to keep false positives to a minimum and search speed to a maximum.

Examples of a VALID match from 0 to 16 are:

```
0 yo
0yo
0-yo
0_yo

00 yo
00yo
00-yo
00_yo

7 yo
7yo
7-yo
7_yo

07 yo
07yo
07-yo
07_yo

14 yo
14yo
14-yo
14_yo
```

Examples of NO match are anything above 16, e.g.:

```
20 yo
20yo
20-yo
20_yo
```

I am hoping to keep the joining character (i.e. - or _) as any white-space or non-white space character so that 14>yo would also match.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will the number always be at the beginning of the string and what flavor of regex are you using (php, javascript, python)?

Comment: It would be better to use a regular expression to extract the numeric part, and then use a simple numeric comparison to tell if it's greater than 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude digits from matching between the number and `yo` (right now, `[\S\s]` matches them).

I suggest:

```
\b(?:1[0-6]|0?[0-9])\D?yo\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV7aN1/1)

*Explanation*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:1[0-6]|0?[0-9])` - 2 alternatives:

  - `1[0-6]` - `1` followed by a digit from `0` to `6`
  - `|` - or...
  - `0?[0-9]` - optional `0` followed by any digit
- `\D?` - one or zero non-digit characters (**note** you can further restrict it  by turning it into a negated character class `[^\d]?`, and add more characters there)
- `yo\b` - a whole word `yo`.